# Can't see how implication on definition of Martingale was arrived at

Tags: probability, expectation, martingales

A Martingale is a discrete time stochastic process $Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_n$ for any time $n$ that satisfies

$E[|Z_n|] < \infty$

$E[Z_{n+1}| Z_0, Z_1, ..., Z_n] = Z_n$

**By the linearity of expectation the second statement is equivalent to**

$E[Z_{n+1} - Z_n| Z_0, Z_1, ..., Z_n] = 0$

I understand linearity of expectation and how it lets us bring values "inside and outside " expected value functions but I don't see how that conclusion was arrived at...

$E[Z_{n+1}| Z_0, Z_1, ..., Z_n] = Z_n$

$\implies E[Z_{n+1}| Z_0, Z_1, ..., Z_n] - Z_n = 0$

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 3):

The random variable $\color{red}{Z_n}$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(Z_0,\dots,Z_{n-1},\color{red}{Z_n})$.

If $\mathcal G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $X$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable then $\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal G]=X$.

Comment: I'm wondering how it gets 'brought inside' the expectation function?

Comment: See edit.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ok cheers, I was unaware of that. Is there another way of saying it without using measure theory? I've done measure theory but my current module on Stochastic Processes is based on people not having done it...so I'm wondering is there another way to get to that result sans measure theory?

Answer (score 2):

You simply have that $$Z_n=E[Z_n|Z_n]$$ or in other words, given that at time $n$ you know $Z_n$ then the expected value of the random variable $Z_n$ will be $Z_n$. Note that the expectation on the right hand side is a random variable and not a number!

Obviously more knowledge does not change that so that also $$Z_n=E[Z_n|Z_0,Z_1,\ldots,Z_n]$$ The best (and most formal) explanation is already given (in another answer) and states that $$E[X|\mathcal G]=X$$ if $\mathcal G$ is $σ-$algebra $X$ is $\mathcal G$-miserable.